# Offline code browser for Android

Tags: android, open-source, git, source-code

Sometimes I'd like to use time during commuting etc. for investigating bugs or issues in some of my projects. Is there a tool for Android that'd allow me to clone a git repository (or another [VCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control)) and browse code offline?

If possible, I'd prefer an open-source one.

Comment: Several possibilities for that, see my list of apps for [Versioning](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_versioning). Haven't tried any of those myself, hence no answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update 2016-11-02

[SGit will no longer be maintained](https://github.com/sheimi/SGit/blob/master/README.md), but the further development will be done under the project [MGit](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=com.manichord.mgit) (GPLv3).

---

<s>the one almost full featured open source (GPLv3) git-client on android i know is [SGit](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=me.sheimi.sgit).</s>

there is also the read only client [Agit](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=com.madgag.agit) (GPLv3) designed for offline access (the full history is stored), but it seems to be [unmaintained since 2014](https://github.com/rtyley/agit)!

Comment: Agit is the way to go for me, as I only need to browse, no need for any changes. Thanks.

Comment: Read-only is exactly what the asker asked for :-) Would you mind expanding your answer with a screenshot? Thanks!