# Git client for Android 4+

Tags: android, offline, git

I am searching for a Git client on Android. I have version 4.

I require:

- reading files locally and commit with message if changes found (local git commit should work offline)
- synchronize with non local git server
- pull request
- git push
- git clone
- gratis
- open source preferred
- ad free preferred

I don't look for text editor/text viewer, I have other programs for that task.

Example use case: I have  files on my Github, and would like to clone the repo, make changes with another text editor , commit the changes, and then push the changes back to the Github

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Offline code browser for Android](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/25606/offline-code-browser-for-android)

Comment: Not using any myself, but take your pick from my app listing on [Versioning with Git](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_versioning#group_963) for a starter :)

Comment: @DJCrashdummy How to push/pull while offline? I don't think the linked question is a duplicate. Walle didn't write anything about "code browsing" here. Git isn't just for development – one can also use it e.g. to manage configuration files (check e.g. [etckeeper](http://joeyh.name/code/etckeeper/)), documents, and more :)

Comment: @Izzy: well, clients for offline-usage also can (and probably must) have online-capabilities... so much offline-clients would fit this requirements.

Comment: @Izzy: ...i know from my answer, at least one does. ;-)

Comment: @DJCrashdummy Agreed it's definitely *related* – but no dupe. The other question just asks to clone and investigate code, while Walle requires also sync, pull, push. True enough one usually doesn't come without the other ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>if this question is not a complete duplicate i'm additionally answering this question:</sub>

---

[MGit](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=com.manichord.mgit) is a git client with extensive features like:

- foss-software (GPLv3)
- gratis and ad-free
- create/search/delete local repositories
- import existing repositories (you can copy a repository from computer and import to MGit)
- clone remote repositories
- manually choose code language
- browse files
- browse commit messages (short)
- checkout branches and tags
- checkout remote branches
- pull from origin
- push merged content
- commit and push changed files
- committer information
- merge branches
- git status
- git rebase
- git cherrypick
- git diff between commits
- git checkout  (reset changes of a file)
- HTTP/HTTPS/SSH are supported (including SSH with private key passphrase)
- username/password authentication is supported (with option to save them)
- private key management

[image: MGit menu]

Comment: I ll try MGit this week

Comment: Is it possible to clone private git repos ?

Comment: @WalleCyril i'm not sure what exactly you are considering a *"private repo"*... but local & remote repos are supported (even importing existing ones) and also username/password and SSH-keys. so i'm pretty sure, yes. **||** but keep in mind MGit is **not** a Github client but a generic git client! so as long as your service (if you are using such a thing) sticks to the "default/norm", chances are high that it is supported.